Is it true that $\#(\mathrm{Ker} f)^⊥=\#\mathrm{Image}(f^*)$ when the pairing is non-degenerate?
Let $f: A → B$ be a homomorphism of a finite abelian groups. For a pairing $A × A → \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$, we denote the orthogonal complement of $\mathrm{Ker} f ⊂ A$ by $(\mathrm{Ker} f)^⊥$. When the pairing is non-degenerate, is it true that  $\#(\mathrm{Ker} f)^⊥=\#\mathrm{Image}(f^*)$ ?
Here, $f^*: B^* → A^*$ represents the dual map between Pontryagin dual.
Any reference is also appreciated.

I don't think there is a "natural" way to show it with isomorphisms for the reason that we can have non-zero elements in $\ker(f) \cap \ker(f)^\bot$, unlike in the case of finite dimensional vector spaces. For example,
$$
f : \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},
$$
given by the projection and the pairing,
$$
\left<a,b\right> = \frac{ab}{4} \mod \mathbb{Z}.
$$
Then $2 \in \ker(f) \cap \ker(f)^\bot$.
Let us decompose $A$ as $A = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^r \mathbb{Z}/n_i\mathbb{Z}$ where the $n_i$ are integers greater than or equal to $2$. Let us show first that $G^\bot \cong A/G$ for any $G \subset A$. Let for all $i$, $e_i \in A$ be the natural generator of $\mathbb{Z}/n_i\mathbb{Z} \subset A$. Let $G \subset A$ be any subgroup. Such a subgroup can be written as,
$$
G = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^r \mathbb{Z}\biggl/\frac{n_i}{k_i}\mathbb{Z},
$$
where $k_i|n_i$ and $\mathbb{Z}\bigl/\frac{n_i}{k_i}\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n_i\mathbb{Z}$ by multiplication by $k_i$. Therefore,
$$
A/G = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^r \mathbb{Z}/k_i\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Then, for all $a \in A$, $a \in G^\bot$ if and only if for all $i$,
$$
\left<a,k_ie_i\right> = k_i\left<a,e_i\right> = 0 \textrm{ in } \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}.
$$
We deduce that $\left<a,e_i\right>$ can be written as the class of $\frac{p_i(a)}{k_i}$ modulo $\mathbb{Z}$ so the integer $p_i(a) \in \mathbb{Z}$ is uniquely defined modulo $k_i$. Let us consider the morphism of groups,
$$
\varphi : \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
G^\bot & \rightarrow & \bigoplus_{i = 1}^r \mathbb{Z}/k_i\mathbb{Z}\\
a & \mapsto & (p_i(a) \mod k_i)_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant r}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
If $\varphi(a) = 0$, then for all $i$, $k_i|p_i(a)$ so
$$
\left<a,e_i\right> = \frac{p_i(a)}{k_i} = 0 \textrm{ in } \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}.
$$
As the pairing is non-degenerate and the $e_i$ generate $A$, $a = 0$ so $\varphi$ is injective.
If $g = (p_i)_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant r} \in \bigoplus_{i = 1}^r \mathbb{Z}/k_i\mathbb{Z}$, let us define,
$$
g^* : \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
A & \rightarrow & \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\\
a = \sum_{i = 1}^r a_ie_i & \mapsto & \sum_{i = 1}^r a_i\frac{p_i}{k_i}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
It is well-defined because $p_i$ is defined modulo $k_i$ so $\frac{p_i}{k_i}$ is defined modulo $1$. $g^* \in A^*$ ans the pairing is non-degenerate so there is a unique $a_g \in A$ such that $g^* = \left<a_g,\cdot\right>$. For all $i$, we have,
$$
\left<a_g,e_i\right> = \frac{p_i}{k_i},
$$
so in particular, $\left<a_g,ke_i\right> = 0$ hence $a_g \in G^\bot$ and $\varphi(a_g) = g$. $\varphi$ is surjective. It show that $G^\bot \cong A/G$ (in a non natural way).
If we want to show that for any $f : A \rightarrow B$, $\ker(f)^\bot$ and $\textrm{im}(f^*)$ are isomorphic, using the isomorphisms $\ker(f)^\bot \cong A/\ker(f)$ and $A/\ker(f) \cong \textrm{im}(f)$, all we have left to show is that $\textrm{im}(f)$ and $\textrm{im}(f^*)$ are isomorphic (the pairing in $A$ is no more useful here). If $f$ is surjective, $\textrm{im}(f) = B$ and $f^*$ is injective so $\textrm{im}(f^*) = B^*$. $B$ and $B^*$ are (non canonically) isomorphic (by considering a non-degenerate pairing on $B$ for example).
In the general case, consider the sequence,
$$
f : A \overset{\tilde{f}}{\twoheadrightarrow} \textrm{im}(f) \hookrightarrow B,
$$
which induces a sequence,
$$
f^* : B^* \twoheadrightarrow \textrm{im}(f)^* \overset{\tilde{f}^*}{\hookrightarrow} A^*.
$$
Therefore, $\textrm{im}(f) = \textrm{im}(\tilde{f}) \cong \textrm{im}(\tilde{f}^*) = \textrm{im}(f^*)$. The non canonical isomorphism $\textrm{im}(\tilde{f}) \cong \textrm{im}(\tilde{f}^*)$ is due to $\tilde{f}$ being surjective.
